# How to get background image to overflow out of div using pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my background image to **overflow out** of its container using pseudo element `::before`, but haven't achieved the effect I want.

When zooming in or out, my background seems to position towards the left instead of the center like specified. I also tried to do `left:40%`, but that then creates a horizontal scroll bar, which I don't want.

```
.hero{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.hero::before{
    content:" ";
    background:url("URL");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 700px;
    top: -220px;
    z-index: -2;
    padding:100px;
    margin:-100px;
}
```

Is there a way to have a background image overflows off screen while centerized?

Comment: position:relative on the hero?

Comment: @temaniAfif doesn't work :/ it just crops my background off

Answer (score 2):

Setting `width:100%` is the issue as it will define the width to be the same as the parent element then you will simply shift the image to the left with the negative margin. There is also the padding added to the width.

Instead you can simply consider top/left/right/bottom like below:

```css
.hero{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:150px;
    border:5px solid red;
    position:relative;
}

.hero::before{
    content:" ";
    background:url("https://picsum.photos/800/1000");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    bottom:-100px;
    left:-100px;
    right:-100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">

</div>
```

Simply make top the same as bottom and left the same as right to have your background centred

Comment: I tried that method but that results in a horizontal bar across screen, is there a way to do this without the scrollbar showing?

Comment: @JaeKT `overflow:hidden` on `html`?

Comment: @JaeKT good, don't forget to accept the answer if it solve your issue